# Sheets or Excel - sum values in column a for each unique date and time in col b

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

I have two columns. One is a value, the other is a date and time:

```
A.                B.   
01/01/21 5.15     3
01/01/21 5.15     2
01/01/21 5.15     4
01/01/21 5.30     2
01/01/21 5.30     3
```

I want the output to be:

```
A.                B.   
01/01/21 5.15     9
01/01/21 5.30     5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your times in Col A are hour-minute as shown (i.e., no seconds):

`=QUERY(A:B, "Select A, SUM(B) WHERE A Is Not Null GROUP BY A LABEL SUM(B) ''")`

This assumes your values start in A1:B1 (i.e., that you have no headers).

A longer but more flexible and easily transferable version of the above:

`=QUERY({A:B}, "Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2) ''")`

Comment: Thanks, Erik - just tried that in my Sheet and it worked a treat!

Comment: Glad to hear it. QUERY is a useful and powerful tool, one worth exploring.